# RegEx to split formatting string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a JS date library which has a simple `asString()` formatting syntax e.g. `dd mmm yyyy` produces `01 Jan 1970`.

Unfortunately should the month happen to contain a letter that appears in the formatting string it can go wrong, e.g. `Date('2014-09-01').asString('dd mmm yyyy') = 01 Septe9ber 2014'

To solve this is quite simple; alter the `asString()` method to use the format '[dd] [mmm] [yyyy]' instead. However this comes from a global format string used by other methods. The only method that needs the square brackets is the `asString` method.

So my ideal solution is to simply add a function in that method which replaces any of the following strings within the `format` string:

```
formats=['yyyy','yy','mmmm','mmm','mm','m','dddd','ddd','dd','d','hh','min','ss'];
```

With itself surrounded by `[]`

```
dd/mm/yyyy => [dd]/[mm]/[yyyy]
```

Unfortunately the RegEx is proving to be complex - simply looping through each item results in `[[d][d]]/[[m][m]]/[[yy][yy]]`.

So I'd like help writing this RegEx. If it can't be done please say so - I'm not interested in using new libraries as a solution but would consider solutions which solved the problem in a different way within the current `asString` method (i.e. no breaking changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
var regex = /(min|y+|m+|d+|h+|s+)/g,
    newString = format.replace(regex,'[$1]');
```

Tested with the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`, resulted in `"[dd]/[mm]/[yyyy]"`

Comment: Tested with a few others and most work. The useful one of `dddd mmmm yy` works. Only time it didn't was `md` producing `[md]` but it's questionable whether anyone would ever want that format. It also turns `min` into `[m]in` but on the whole it works. Thanks!

Comment: @M1ke Edited my answer to fix the `[m]in` and `[md]` issue. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it using the check mark below the vote count. Thank you.